# Flutter: add a simple wrapper to the Text widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I came from a React world and trying to get my head around Flutter and Dart.

I'm using the Text widget with the same parameters a lot, so it seems reasonable to think of a way to reuse code. I created a wrapper that uses it:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TextStyle getThemeProperty(type, TextTheme textTheme) {
  switch (type) {
    case 'headline1':
      return textTheme.headline1;
    case 'headline2':
      return textTheme.headline2;
    case 'headline3':
      return textTheme.headline3;
    default:
      return textTheme.bodyText2;
  }
}

class CustomText extends StatelessWidget {
  const CustomText({Key key, this.type, this.text, this.color}) : super(key: key);

  final type;
  final text;
  final color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    var style = getThemeProperty(type, textTheme);

    if (this.color != null) style.color = this.color; 

    return Text(
      this.text,      
      style: style,
    );
  }
}

// Usage
CustomText(
  text: 'Some Heading',
  type: 'headline2',
  color: Colors.black
)
```

The idea is to set the color if the color property is passed as a parameter, but Dart's compiler doesn't like it. It throws me the error: *''color' can't be used as a setter because it's final.
Try finding a different setter, or making 'color' non-final.'*

I'm planning to do the same to `fontWeight` and `textAlign` properties as well. How am I able to make this work, I mean, to add new props to the style object on demand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the dart compiler is unhappy is just because the `color` property of the `TextStyle` is declared as final. Therefore to use a new color, you have to create a new instance of the `TextStyle`.

Luckily, the TextStyle class comes with a copyWith method that returns an edited copy of your TextStyle

```
  final type;
  final text;
  final color;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;
    var style = getThemeProperty(type, textTheme);
    
    return Text(
      this.text,    
      // Added this...
      style: style.copyWith(color: color ?? style.color),
    );
  }
```

As a side note, when making reusable widgets, it's always a good idea to type your parameters. This is because any type of variable can be used. So instead of passing a `String` for text, you may pass an `int`

```
// DON'T DO THIS
final type;
final text;
final color;

// DO THIS
final String type;
final String text;
final Color color;
```

Also adding the `this` keyword to reference a variable in a class without variable shadowing is unnecessary.

```
// DON'T
this.text
// DO
text
```